# Simplify functions so this does not get too big

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code so that each element make the scroll effect when done: I keep repeating the function to each element, the problem that are 8 elements with different classes to add functions, the code would be very large.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#section6').each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 200) {
            svgEstatua.start();
        }
    });

});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#section2').each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 225) {
            svgBrain.start();
        }
    });

});
// must 5
```

array:

```
var groupSvg = [svgManos, svgSuper, svgInnovation, svgEstatua, svgBrain, svgBalanza];
```

Comment: $("#someid").each doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the common code and do something like this

```
function common(selector, svgObject, offset) {
    $(selector).each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top,
            topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + offset) {
            svgObject.start();
        }
    });
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    common('#section6', svgEstatua, 200);
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    common('#section2', svgBrain, 225);
});
```

You can then use your array or an object to loop though.

Comment: dont need the each, when selecting an element by id.

Comment: This is generic, if the `selector` is not an ID, but a `class` for example, or if combines the selector to choose multiple IDs. I am just using the OP's example.